# VBA Code to Pull data through solver and paste on different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I am having difficulty figuring out why my VBA code isn't working (is only partially working) and feel as though it has something to do with integrating solver into my VBA. I am new to Stack Overflow, so I apologize if I do not post my problem correctly. Attached is a copy of my code, and screenshots of my three sheets where the code interfaces and the results on the third worksheet where the final values should be shown.

Please note, values are blacked out of my screenshots due to security measures.

Feel free to ask any questions to further clarify my problem.

```
Sub WorkingLoop()
'
' WorkingLoop Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L
'

SolverOptions StepThru:=False

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Modified Data")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Solver | Macro")
Set sht3 = wb.Sheets("New Price")

LastRow = sht1.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row


For i = 2 To LastRow
sht2.Range("A2") = sht1.Range("A" & i).Value
sht2.Range("F2:F7") = sht2.Range("D2:D7").Value

SolverOk SetCell:="$B$14", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$12", _
Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

sht3.Range("A" & i) = sht2.Range("A2").Value
sht3.Range("D" & i) = sht2.Range("B10").Value
sht3.Range("E" & i) = sht2.Range("B11").Value
sht3.Range("F" & i) = sht3.Range("B17").Value
sht3.Range("G" & i) = sht3.Range("B18").Value
sht3.Range("H" & i) = sht3.Range("B19").Value
sht3.Range("I" & i) = sht3.Range("B20").Value
sht3.Range("J" & i) = sht3.Range("B21").Value
sht3.Range("K" & i) = sht3.Range("B22").Value

Next i

End Sub
```

1. Sheet1: Values that will be used to move through the solver
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhUZn.png
2. Sheet2: Where values from ModData move through the solver
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KUwU.png
3. Sheet3: Where new prices are to be posted after running through the solver
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2HGd.png

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `sht3.Range("F" & i) = **sht3**.Range("B17").Value` is that *really* what you want to do?  You are copying from your summary sheet, not the solver sheet.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks, code works fine now.

Comment: VTC as being a typographical error...